# I can't write to a folder which I'm a member of

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm trying to setup folder access to a group so that all members of that group can create/edit/delete files within the folder.

```
# create my group and add a member
sudo addgroup dev
sudo adduser martyn dev
```

Now, logged in as "martyn", check my user has been added to "dev" group

```
groups martyn
martyn : martyn dev
```

Now I want to change the group ownership of my project folder so all members of that group can edit it and files/folders within it.

```
sudo chgrp -R dev myproject
```

Just to check:

```
martyn@localhost:/var/www$ ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 3 dev dev 4096 May 31 15:53 myproject
```

Now here's where it fails. I want to create a file within myproject (logged in as "martyn", a member of "dev"):

```
vi myproject/test
```

..but when I try to save the file I get the following error:

```
"myproject/test" E212: Can't open file for writing
```

Why, as user "martyn" which is a member of "dev", can I not write this file? Even if I create the file so it exists, change the ownership to "dev" then try to edit and save - I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to change/set the ownership of the directory with the `chown` command, like this:

```
chown -R dev:dev myproject/
```

and then set the permissions with the `chmod` command:

```
chmod -R 0775 myproject/
```

The `0775` bit notation sets the directory mode to `rwxrwxr-x`, which gives the user `dev` and all members of the `dev` group `rwx` access to the directory and files.

Try this instead of the `chgrp` command. You may also try to reboot your machine, just in case. Good luck.

Comment: Could the downvoter at least note what is wrong with this answer?

Comment: I don't know what the down vote was for but anyway you solved my problem. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm always glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Arch Linux:

```
$ sudo useradd martyn
$ sudo passwd martyn
$ sudo groupadd example 
$ sudo usermod --append --groups example martyn
$ sudo mkdir /var/www /var/www/myproject
$ sudo chgrp example /var/www/myproject
$ sudo chmod g+w /var/www/myproject
$ su - martyn
$ groups
example martyn
$ touch /var/www/myproject/file
$ ls -l /var/www/myproject/file
-rw-r--r-- 1 martyn martyn 0 May 31 11:13 /var/www/myproject/file
```

Are you sure you don't have SELinux enabled (run `getenforce`)?

Comment: Thanks. No I don't have SELinux installed.